# Using perl as a better grep to match multiple lines using single line mode m/RE/s

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to grep for a text between to expressions (say `BEGIN` and `END`) that may not be on the same line with:

```
perl -wln -e 'm/BEGIN.+END/s and print;' < file.txt
```

Note that because of the `s` modifier (in `m/RE/s`), `"."` is allowed to match newline (along with anything else).

This lets the pattern match the words in the specific order with anything between them (i.e. pattern `BEGIN` is on one line while pattern `END` is on a few lines below).
If the two patterns are on the same line this works fine, but not when it spans multiple line. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I did figure out the missing part! I needed to use the `-0777` option to search through the whole file as on record and print the matched expression using `print $&` instead:

```
perl -wln -0777 -e 'm/BEGIN.+END/s and print $&;' < file.txt
```

Comment: will do so as soon as it does allow me so (in two days)