# Display n lines before and m lines after a pattern match were n & m are themselves pattern matches

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have data like this:

```
foo
...
bar
...
pattern
...
]
```

I need to first match to 'pattern' and then display everything before 'pattern' up to 'foo' and everything after pattern down to ']'

grep should do this:

```
grep pattern -A grep foo -B grep ]
```

But alas it does not.

Answer doesn't need to include grep. 
awk, sed and others welcome.

Comment: so what is the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: Your sample input is inadequate. Show sample input that includes cases where ranges overlap and/or the start/end of file occur before/after your expected range, etc. and the associated output. Also define "pattern" (ais it a stginr, a BRE, an ERE or something else?) and show whether you want whole "word"s or whole lines only to match or partial matches. Otherwise we're just guessing at almost all of your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soo...you want to print a section between something that matches `foo` and something that matches `]` if it contains something that matches `pattern`, is that correct? Then

```
sed -n '/foo/ { :a; N; /\]/!ba /pattern/ p }' filename
```

The sed code works as follows:

```
/foo/ {       # if a line matches foo
  :a          # jump label
  N           # fetch the next line and append it to the pattern space
  /\]/! ba    # if the result does not match ] (that is, if the last fetched
              # line does not contain something that matches ]), go back to :a
  /pattern/ p # if in all these lines, there is something that matches the
              # pattern, print them
}
```

To make the match non-greedy at the front -- that is to say, if in a file

```
1
foo
2
foo
3
pattern
4
]
5
```

the match should include `3` and `4` but not `2`, the script could be amended like this (or similar, depending on the patterns you want to use):

```
sed -n '/foo/ { :a; N; /\n[^\n]*foo/ s/.*\n//; /\]/!ba /pattern/ p }' filename
```

Where `/\n[^\n]*foo/ s/.*\n//` will remove everything before the last fetched line if something in that line matches `foo`.

If your patterns are line patterns (i.e., if they contain `^` or `$`), they will need to be amended. Once there is more than one line in the pattern space, `^` will match the beginning and `$` the end *of the pattern space*, not of a line. You can then use `\n` to match line endings. For example, if you wanted to match non-greedily between lines that are exactly `foo` and `]` if there's a line between them that is exactly `pattern`, you could use

```
sed -n '/^foo$/ { :a; N; /\nfoo$/ s/.*\n//; /\n\]$/!ba /\npattern\n/ p }' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '/foo/ {t=1} t {a[++b]=$0} /pattern/ {f=1} /^]/ {if (f) for (i=1;i<=b;i++) print a[i];delete a;b=t=f=0}' file
```

Example data

```
cat file
foo
data
more
]
foo
...
bar
...
pattern
...
]
more
foo
here
yes
]
end
```

Test with `awk`

```
awk '/foo/ {t=1} t {a[++b]=$0} /pattern/ {f=1} /^]/ {if (f) for (i=1;i<=b;i++) print a[i];delete a;b=t=f=0}'
foo
...
bar
...
pattern
...
]
```

Some more easy to read:

```
awk '
/foo/ {t=1} 
t {a[++b]=$0} 
/pattern/ {f=1} 
/^]/ {if (f) 
    for (i=1;i<=b;i++) 
        print a[i]
    delete a
    b=t=f=0
    }
'
```

Test if `foo` is found, set `t` to true
If `t` is true, store all line in array `a`
If `pattern` is found, set flag  `f`
If `]` is found, test if flag `f` is true, then print array `a`
Reset every ting and start over.

Answer (score 0):

single line using perl:

```
perl -wln -0777 -e 'm/foo((?!foo).)*pattern[^\]]*\]/s and print $&;' [filename]
```

input:

```
foo
foo
...
bar
...
pern
...
]
]
foo
... 
pattern
]
]
foo
]
```

output:

```
perl -wln -0777 -e 'm/foo((?!foo).)*pattern[^\]]*\]/s and print $&;' testtest
foo
... 
pattern
]
```

[analysis on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eC3eP9/1)

Some key points:

1. turn on single line mode with `m/.../s` in perl refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925902/using-perl-as-a-better-grep-to-match-multiple-lines-using-single-line-mode-m-re):
2. regex `foo((?!foo).)*pattern[^\]]*\]`

   - `foo` match the first foo
   - `((?!foo).)*` avoid matching `foo` in matching part using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
   - `pattern` match pattern
   - `[^\]]*\]` the following part should not contain `]` and end with `]`